# Getting both group size and min of column B grouping by column A

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

Given a DataFrame `df`, I can obtain the size of groups by column A with

```
df.groupby(['columnA']).size()
```

and the mimimun value of column B within each group with

```
df.groupby(['columnA']).agg({'columnB':min})
```

or (syntactic sugar I guess)

```
df.groupby(['columnA'])['columnB'].min()
```

but how can I obtain directly a DataFrame with such 2 columns?

In SQL, if you comfortable with it, this would be as simple as

```
SELECT count(columnA), min(columnB) FROM table GROUP BY columnA
```

Thanks in advance for any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing both of them in [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) should work, since `agg` permits a list of functions.

```
>>> df
  columnA  columnB  columnC
0    cat1        3      400
1    cat1        2       20
2    cat1        5     3029
3    cat2        1      492
4    cat2        4       30
5    cat3        2      203
6    cat3        6      402
7    cat3        4      391

>>> df.groupby(['columnA']).columnB.agg(['size', 'min'])
         size  min
columnA           
cat1        3    2
cat2        2    1
cat3        3    2

>>> df.groupby(['columnA']).agg(['size', 'min'])
        columnB     columnC     
           size min    size  min
columnA                         
cat1          3   2       3   20
cat2          2   1       2   30
cat3          3   2       3  203
```

`agg` also accepts a dict of columns -> functions, and so were you to want to map a function to each column individually you could do so with something (*not necessary here*) like

```
df.groupby(['columnA']).agg({'columnA':'size','columnB':'min‌​'})
```

Comment: I think that your first answer `df.groupby(['columnA']).agg({'columnA':'size','columnB':'min'})` was more general and useful in real world. I would suggest to add it back.

Comment: @mmj Sure, I can add a blurb about using dicts.

Comment: You might be interested in tackling the follow up of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42399574/694360